# How is there whitespace in integer column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I load two dfs each from their own csv file. They were generated seperately and I don't have control of that. The first one seems to have whitespace even though it is an integer dtype.

```
In: df1 = read_csv(file1.csv)
In: df2 = read_csv(file2.csv)

In: df1['key'].head().values
Out: array([    1,    10,   100,  1000, 10000], dtype=int64)
In: print(df1['key'].head().values) #using print()
Out: [    1    10   100  1000 10000]

In: df2['key'].head().values
Out: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
In: print(df1['key'].head().values) #using print()
Out: [1 2 3 4 5]
```

So I can't join them on this column - none match. But it doesn't actually seem there is whitespace:

```
In: df1['key'].astype(str).head().values
Out: array(['1', '10', '100', '1000', '10000'], dtype=object)
```

And using `.str.strip()` and/or `.str.replace(' ','')` do not work. Which makes sense since it probably doesn't have traditional string whitespace.

```
In: df1['key'].astype(str).str.replace(' ','').astype(int).head().values
Out: array([    1,    10,   100,  1000, 10000], dtype=int64)
```

I just don't even know how to search google for this. What sort of whitespace am I dealing with? How do I clean it up? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is just how pandas is displaying the values to make it "prettier" and more formatted, you don't need to worry about those whitespaces.

Comment: Actually there is no white spaces.

Comment: You say that you can't join them. Maybe the problem is with that statement. What command are you using for the join?

Comment: I just added print() for each but still there is 'whitespace' - I believe you that it's not there - but I can't prove it - I'll add the join statement as well

Comment: @Craig (actually all of you) I think you're right - when I pull this out into a smaller test the join works. Something else is going on here...

Comment: There was an issue with the join. The seeming whitespace did not impact the join. I still don't know how to control/remove that whitespace. So I'll leave this question open if someone wants to answer that.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by @TYZ, the whitespace is added by pandas when the values are printed to make the formatting look nice. It isn't stored anywhere in the dataframe. To display things this way, `pandas` defines the `__str__()` method for `pandas.DataFrame` and `pandas.Series` objects. This method is called when Python converts an object to a `str` type, such as when displaying it in the interpreter or using the `print()` function.

When `pandas` returns data as an array (from `.values`) it is a `numpy.ndarrray`, which also has a custom `__str__()` method for pretty printing.

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'key':[    1,    10,   100,  1000, 10000]} )

In [3]: print(df1)
     key
0      1
1     10
2    100
3   1000
4  10000
```

The numbers are automatically right justified so that the output looks nice.

```
In [4]: type(df1['key'].values)
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray

In [5]: df1['key'].values
Out[5]: array([    1,    10,   100,  1000, 10000], dtype=int64)

In [6]: print(df1['key'].values)
[    1    10   100  1000 10000]
```

The `.values` attribute returns a `numpy.ndarray` which also uses a custom `__str__()` method for formatting.

The `pandas` and `numpy.ndarray` formatting is based on the contents that are being printed. A dataframe with only single-digit numbers prints without additional padding. Appending a multi-digit number to the dataframe causes all of the single-digit numbers to be printed with padding to be equal in length to the longest number. This example shows how the padding depends on the items that are being printed.

```
In [11]: df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'key':[1,2,3,4,5]} )

In [12]: print(df2['key'].values)
[1 2 3 4 5]

In [13]: print(df2.append({'key':1000}, ignore_index=True)['key'].values)
[   1    2    3    4    5 1000]
```

If you want to display the data without the pretty formatting, you can always convert it to a Python `list`.

```
In [21]: print(df1['key'].tolist())
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

Comment: This is a great explanation but can you connect the dots for me between this answer and how one of my dataframes had the pretty formatting and one did not - even though I used the same function and ultimately the same `__str__()` method?

Comment: Both of your dataframes have the pretty formatting, The second one only displays single-digit numbers, so it doesn't pad with extra spaces to make them all take up the same width.